# Error : Could not find HelloAndroid.apk

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android development. I followed every steps from developer.com to install ADK. Now my issue is, when I tried to run HelloAndroid application, I get an error as I mentioned in the title.
I hav JRE1.6 installed. Is tat enuf? Because I read tat ether jdk or jre is ok. I am clearly blank about the concept of this apk error. And I am using Eclipse Ganymede. Kindly give a solution for my issue. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try in eclipse: Project -> Clean... -> Your android project

Helped in my case. However, I was developing and successful building apk's with eclipse for months before this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by re-booting eclipse. I suggest you try this first.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot one major issue.

JRE alone is insufficient. Here is an extract of their development system requirements.

> JDK 5 or JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)

Here you can find their page on system requirements. http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

I'm not sure but I guess your error comes from not having the JDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I solved by using JRE system library 1.6 instead of 1.5.  My post cronicles all the other solutions I've seen online, hope it helps.

[apk issue post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and didn't really see easy advice on the internet. To fix it, I followed these steps.  #1 may not be necessary, so try #2 first alone.

1. Upgrade the JDK from 1.5 to
   [1.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u26-download-400750.html). Even if you bypass this step, ensure you have a JDK installed.
2. Removed/Delete the project completely then create a new HelloAndroid project. A config setting is occasionally off. Obviously back up the source code if the project is more important to you than a Hello World application.

If it works, you may encounter a timeout error after launch when the HelloAndroid.apk is installing in your emulator. Change the timeout from 5000ms to 10000ms in

Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection timeout(ms).

Good luck!