# Unable to run Android app, Could not find .apk issue in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

Recently I have updated my ADT plugin of eclipse to the latest one but after that I use to face an unusual problem. When ever I try to run my Android projects on emulator or device, all my projects are keep on saying

Could not find [project name].apk

Please help me.

Comment: Checkout this thread: [Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

Comment: Adnan, I have tried the link but it did not worked for me :(

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Eclipse Ganymede Version: 3.4.2

Comment: I fixed same issue by switching to Eclipse Helios 3.6

Comment: have you also update the ADT plugin with the latest one?

Comment: Yes I have updated it to ADT 10.0.0

Comment: this has not solved my problem

Comment: If u have installed Eclipse Helios, right click on your project, select Android Tools and click Fix Project Properties. Then clean your project, this should solve your problem. Keep looking at Markers tab at bottom for any errors.

Comment: all goes to vain dear.. still facing the same issue

Comment: Andan, thx, saved me few hours probably (advice about fix project properties)

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. There were no build errors reported in console of eclipse on ubuntu 10.10, still apk wasnt generated. point JAVA_HOME to correct path and rebuild the project. Eclipse didn't pick the location of java somehow.