# Unable to generate apk using Eclipse

Tags: android, apk, adt

Very new to Android development and am running into some issues with basic stuff.  I've been using Eclipse to build my projects.  Recently I upgraded to the latest version of the eclipse ADT plug-in v15.0.0 and in the process also had to upgrade my Android SDK to v15.

Now when I build my application there is no apk file generated.  A dialog box with a progress bar appears with messages indicating that something is getting built.  There are no errors but in the end I do not see an apk file in the bin directory or any other directory under project.

I have tried the following
- deleted project from Eclipse and re-imported the project
- deleted project from Eclipse and made a new project from exisisting source
- deleted project from Eclipse, removed code from workspace, re-synced to code from server and created a new project from existing source

To make things simple I tried building the hello-jni example that ships with the NDK and observed the same issue; dialog shows build with no errors but there is no apk.  The suggestions in the threads below did not fix the issue for me.

[Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)
[Unable to run Android app, Could not find .apk issue in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219208/unable-to-run-android-app-could-not-find-apk-issue-in-eclipse)

Details about my set up below
Java 6 Update 27
JDK  6 Update 27
Eclipse 3.7.1
ADT Plugin v15
Android SDK v15
Win 7 (32-bit)

The only thought I have is to uninstall and then reinstall the SDK.  Seemed like it might be worth checking with the more experienced folks before I did that.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning the project and then running

`android update project --name <project_name> --target <target_ID>
--path <path_to_your_project>`

from the command line. Then try building again.

Also, go to your project properties in Eclipse and go to 'Builders' and make sure that you see 'Android Package Builder' as one of the builders listed there..