# Library doesn't generate jar file

Tags: android, android-library

I created an Android library in Eclipse, marked as library and without errors.

I then created a project, which should use this library. The project code is fine, I checked all under Order and Export, but the library jar doesn't build.

I double checked almost everything, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Why do You expect to have jar file for that library? If Your second project depends on it, then it might be just included in the same apk. Also, have You checked output folder for library project?

Comment: Does this happen during development, i.e. with unsigned App, or only when you try to export the signed app. I ran into a similar problem in the latter case and could perhaps asist you with it.

Comment: It happens during developement. I simply did all the step as ninetwozero said, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you should only need to do the following:

1. Right click on the library project, and select "Project properties"
2. Go to the Android tab
3. Mark project as library
4. Go back and right click on your actual application project and open up the properties
5. Go to the Android tab
6. Add the library project as a library
7. Build all projects
8. Run the app in the emulator/your device

That said, I've never really had any problems with it - I just hook it up as a library as described above, and I'm all set.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but it doesn't build the apk.

Comment: The application apk, or the library apk? Guessing the second. :-) If so, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6118122/860212

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the jar file, check to see in

```
Eclipse IDE -> Project Explorer -> Your Project Folder -> Android Dependencies -> Your Library Project as jar file.
```

Please check this path and there should be jar file.

Comment: Checked, but the jar doesn't appear.

Comment: Have u checked in Project -> Properties -> Android Tab -> Scroll down -> Check whether library project with green tick symbol is there aor not. Please update me

Comment: Yes it is green, it founds it.

Comment: Ok. Right click on Project -> Build Path -> Click "Order and Export" tab -> Please check "Android Private Libraries", "Android Dependencies" checked or not.