# Android Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have been going though the android tutorial on the developer site, and have run while trying to add actions to the Action bar (I am using the Support Library to support version 2.1+), I keep getting the error android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find `android-support-v7-appcompat.apk`!.

The app still runs and functions, though the Action bar does not have the buttons I added. I've read other posts on this issue, and made sure that I included android-support-v7-appcompat as a library.

Is there anything I need to add to the build path (not in order and export I already have it checked off there)?

Thanks!
Forgot to mention that I am using eclipse in case it wasn't clear.
After digging around reading some more posts, it seems strange that my app still runs since others with this problem have theirs crash.

NOTE: Not sure if this matters but I had to manually add the string "action_search" for android:title = "@string/action_search" in main_activity_actions.xml (in res/menu/)- should this have been added automatically with appcompat?

Full console output below:

```
[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] Android Launch!

[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] adb is running normally.

[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] Performing com.example.myfirstapp1.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD1'

[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] Uploading MyFirstApp1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2013-08-24 13:19:04 - MyFirstApp1] Installing MyFirstApp1.apk...

[2013-08-24 13:19:08 - MyFirstApp1] Success!

[2013-08-24 13:19:08 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!

[2013-08-24 13:19:08 - MyFirstApp1] Starting activity com.example.myfirstapp1.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

[2013-08-24 13:19:09 - MyFirstApp1] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
cmp=com.example.myfirstapp1/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Found the solution!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580575/could-not-find-the-xxx-apk-message-in-console-while-starting-application-with

Answer (score 20):

Go to Java Build Path > Projects and remove the incorrect project dependency (your Android library project.) Note that in the "Android" section of the project settings the Android library that you're dependent on must be listed in the ~"Libraries" box.

Comment: That is right. The tutorial is not correct, and you need don't add anything in the Properties -> Java Build Path. Instead in the Properties -> Android -> Library add the android-support-v7-appcompat.

Answer (score 8):

maybe you can remove the android-support-v7-appcompat project from your build path.
In Eclipse:
 - Right click into your project
 - Properties
 - List item
 - Java Build Path
 - Projects
 - under "Required projects on the build path:"
 --> select "android-support-v7-appcompat" and click "remove"

This have been solved the problem for me.

Comment: True you don't need it on the build path but you DO need to add it under project Properties -> Android -> Library. The tutorial was misleading.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above post! when create a library project check the checkbox "copy project into work space"

Answer (score 1):

If your actionbar buttons aren't displaying properly when using Appcompat its possible that you're not using the right schema to configure your buttons.

If you're using Appcompat you need to use the schema as shown below on the "yourapp" fields for the API11+ settings such as showAsAction and actionLayout.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I had already done that- I followed all the directions on the tutorial on the developer site

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (except my app crashed).

Basically, I just followed the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) on the android site.

I had the following things wrong, and once fixed, the app ran as expected:

- Didn't add the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to the build path (step 5)
- Didn't export android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to the build path (step 7)
- Had the android-support-v7-appcompat project added on the build path (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Projects)

Once I fixed these things, I needed to remove and re-add the android-support-v7-appcompat project as a library (Project > Properties > Android > Library > Add)

Hope the link above helps anyone coming across this page.