# Could not find appcompat_v7.apk

Tags: java, android

When I try to run my progrm, it works, but when I look at the console, it states that it `Could not find appcompat_v7.apk`.

How do I  try to answer this? I just imported most of my resources.

This is what happens when I do this:  `Properties` > `Android` > `Library add the android-support-v7-appcompat`

```
[2014-04-30 16:28:38 - appcompat_v7] Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!
[2014-04-30 16:28:38 - finalssample1] Starting activity com.example.finalssample1.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-04-30 16:28:40 - finalssample1] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.finalssample1/.MainActivity }
[2014-04-30 16:28:40 - finalssample1] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, read http://stackoverflow.com/a/18548129/603270

Comment: I am using eclipse sir, when I followed it, then app now woudn't run.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse: - Right click on your project - Properties -Java Build Path - then under "Projects" tab, select "android-support-v7-appcompat" and click "remove".

You don't need it there. Solved the problem for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The appcompat 7 is support library. It is not meant to be compiled in an application. When it is marked as library, eclipse will not try to compile it and you will not see the error message. Your main project should not be marked as a library in order to run it as apk.

Comment: then what should i do sir?

Comment: Mark appcompat as library project. Do not mark your main project as library project. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_flag

Comment: still wouldn't find appcompat

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the appcompat 7 is support library. What you could do is, create a new android project. This will create a new appcombat-project (appcombt_v7_2). then delete the old appcombat-library in your project and add the new one. maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

When adding referenced libraries we need only `google-play-services_lib.jar`. So that we need to remove the project from your project.

```
Project->Properties->javaBuildPath->Project->select google-play-services->remove.
```

clean and build.

Succes for me in google-play-services