# first android app gets unfortunately stopped in device

Tags: android

Whenever I try to run my first app the hello world app without any changes, I get this error:

> VM aborting
>  Fatal signal 6(SIGABRT) at 0x00007ec3(code=-6),thread
>   32451(xample.justjava)

What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Below is the error from console:

> [2015-06-26 21:35:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!

Comment: This is not the complete stacktrace. Please post the full stacktrace to enable us to help further. Also the relevant code part.

Comment: i am new to it so i need 10 reputation to post image but i have only 3 so i can't post image.what should i do

Comment: Post a link to the image or copy the stacktrace text and put it in the question.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse to develop your app? Also, please make yourself familiar with the concept of stack traces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/1058424

Answer (score 0):

The last error message posted indicates that your application is missing the android-support-v7-appcompat library. This is a library that enables the backwards compatibility of many UI features as described [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7). It is required for the default Android code examples to work.

Please make sure that you have downloaded the support packages with the SDK manager and attached the resources to your project as described [in the official setup guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

**Edit:**
The console error also indicates that you have accidentally compiled the library apk itself to the project, which should not be done. Please check these links: [Could not find appcompat_v7.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382583/could-not-find-appcompat-v7-apk) and [Android Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421274/android-could-not-find-android-support-v7-appcompat-apk-error)

Comment: yes i have installed android support library and attached it but also it shows same error

Comment: I edited my answer. But that issue is not a crashing issue, so it's not the fault to your crash. Please post the stack trace as requested.