# android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk

Tags: android

I am using [android-support-v7-appcompat] for android project in eclipse. I am getting this error 
             "android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-   v7-appcompat.apk!".

Comment: Please show us your code or some more info about your error like error log etc.

Comment: remove the appcompat labrary from java build path

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382583/could-not-find-appcompat-v7-apk

Comment: I removed appcompat library from buiid path. Same error is throwing

Comment: @ArkarAung  There is no proper answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382583/could-not-find-appcompat-v7-apk

Comment: @DroidDev: In LogCat Iam getting this error.  
08-19 11:37:15.753: E/AndroidRuntime(7384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.powermeterlogin/com.example.powermeterlogin.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: There is no problem in code. The problem is in appcompat package