# Appcompat_7 is not found

Tags: android

```
[2014-11-28 01:06:23 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] ------------------------------
[2014-11-28 01:06:23 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Android Launch!
[2014-11-28 01:06:23 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-28 01:06:23 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Performing info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-11-28 01:06:23 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'first'
[2014-11-28 01:06:24 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
**[2014-11-28 01:06:24 - appcompat_v7] Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!**
[2014-11-28 01:06:24 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Project dependency found, installing: DemoGoogleMapsV2
[2014-11-28 01:06:26 - DemoGoogleMapsV2] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-11-28 01:06:26 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] Starting activity info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-28 01:06:27 - GoogleMapsAndroidv2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2/.MainActivity }
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the appcompat-v7 library from Projects in the Build Path. And don't set it as Order and Export in the Order and Export tab in the Build Path. But set the library in the Properties->Android. Make sure it has a check mark and you are good to go.

A good question about this here: [Android Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421274/android-could-not-find-android-support-v7-appcompat-apk-error)

Comment: Thanks a lot.error took my a lot of time best wishes