# findViewbyId returns null - but not when put into a button onClick listener

Tags: android, null, oncreate, findviewbyid

I want to access a `TextView` to exhange its label.
However, `findViewById` seems to return null when the code is in **onCreate**(), **onResume**() or **onStart**(). The application crashes only if the

```
//if(Day != null)
```

is not commented by //.

The code snippet works fine when put into a `onClickListener` of a `Button`, no `NullPointerException`.

I have really read a lot of solutions yet (cleaning the project, moving the code to `onCreateView` etc.), but none of them worked for me.
So I'm really hoping for your help :P

My *Activity* is

```
package edu.uahwi.smac;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HoursActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //hides the title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hours);

    final PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    long ChosenDate = (long) getIntent().getExtras().getLong("DateLong");
    args.putLong("DateLong", ChosenDate);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    */
    /*
    TextView Day1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDay);
    //if(Day != null)
        Day1.setText(String.valueOf(ChosenDate));*/

}

public void onStart()
{

}

public void Hour2onClick(View v)
{
    startActivity( new Intent("edu.uahwi.smac.BookingConfirmedActivity"));
}

public void buttonClick(View v)
{
    //startActivity( new Intent("edu.uahwi.smac.BookingConfirmedActivity"));


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hours, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    private long chosenDate; // = 10l; 
                             //= (long) getIntent().getExtras().getLong("DateLong");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hours, container, false);

        TextView Day1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDay);
        Day1.setText(String.valueOf(chosenDate));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null)
            chosenDate = args.getLong("DateLong");
    }
}
```

}

The start of the *XML-Code*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="edu.uahwi.smac.HoursActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDay1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/ChosenDay"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="208dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And finally my *Stack-Trace*:

```
05-19 23:12:01.649: W/dalvikvm(1596): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 

exception (group=0xb2addba8)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596): Process: edu.uahwi.smac, PID: 1596
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.uahwi.smac/edu.uahwi.smac.HoursActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at edu.uahwi.smac.HoursActivity.onCreate(HoursActivity.java:36)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-19 23:12:01.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1596):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: is HoursActivity extends Activity or fragment? what's on line no.36?

Comment: HoursActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
This was created autmatically when I told Eclipse to create a new Activity. 

Is it maybe because of the errors reported when I launch the app?
`[2014-05-21 13:46:11 - SmaC] Installing SmaC.apk...
[2014-05-21 13:46:28 - SmaC] Success!
[2014-05-21 13:46:28 - library] Could not find library.apk!
[2014-05-21 13:46:28 - appcompat_v7] Could not find appcompat_v7.apk!
[2014-05-21 13:46:28 - SmaC] Starting activity edu.uahwi.smac.MainActivity on device emulator-5554`
...

Line 36 contained: `Day1.setText(String.valueOf(ChosenDate));`

Comment: please log your `ChosenDate`, may be its null. Add appcompact library.

Comment: ChosenDate is definetly not null, I tried to set it manually.
The problem with the errors on startup concerning some libraries is now fixed with the help of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580575/could-not-find-the-xxx-apk-message-in-console-while-starting-application-with], but still the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That TextView is in the fragment.  You need to move the code that sets the text value to the Fragment's onCreateView(), when you are sure the fragment's views exist.  Like this:

```
private long chosenDate;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);

    TextView Day1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDay1);
    Day1.setText(String.valueOf(chosenDate));
```

And you can pass in chosenDate to the fragment arguments so it will be available to the fragment.  Start your fragment like this from the Activity:

```
final PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
long ChosenDate = (long) getIntent().getExtras().getLong("DateLong");
args.putLong("DateLong", ChosenDate);
fragment.setArguments(args);
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Then in the fragment's onCreate, you can extract the argument and set the local private long to that value, so it will be available later in the onViewCreate call:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null)
        chosenDate = args.getLong("DateLong");
```

Comment: Hello Doug, thanks for your help.
However, it still crashes.
I now get a stack trace saying:
`05-21 01:47:08.163: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {edu.uahwi.smac/edu.uahwi.smac.HoursActivity} did not call through to super.onStart()`
To get the code compiled I had to add `rootView.` before findViewById in your first code snippet.

And your second code snippet, do I use it in the onCreate method of the Activity which I posted above?

Comment: The first and third code snippets are modifications that need to be in your Fragment class.  The second code snippet is a modification to your Activity class where it creates the Fragment, and that shows how to pass an argument to your fragment class.  The onStart() exception just sounds like you have an onStart() method in your Activity that is not calling super.onStart().

Comment: I have done as you told me, but still not working and still the same error as in the first comment. To make it easier I have replaced my whole java code above by the new one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You either need to remove the empty onStart() method from the acyivity or add a line to it that calls super.onStart()

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.
I just built the activity new and from the scratch, tried your code - and now it works like a charm :-)
Don't know where the bug was...