# Error when trying to use Android AppCompat library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have an Android project in which I'd like to use the appcompat library. I have read the following posts and followed their advice:

[Could not find Library.apk!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

["Could not find the XXX.apk" message in console while starting application with an Android lib linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580575/could-not-find-the-xxx-apk-message-in-console-while-starting-application-with)

When trying to add the library project to my project, I get a green check indicating all is fine (see pic 1 below). After I press OK and open Properties again, this green check is replaced with a red X and there doesn't seem to be a way to get a textual error message (see pic 2). In pic 3 you see what libraries are on the Java build path.

Pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgfII.jpg

Needless to say, I can't build my project. The line

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar t;
```

gets the error "android.support.v7 cannot be resolved to a type". I don't see where my setup is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i recall correctly you need to ensure the library is stored on the SAME drive letter as eclipse/your project (Probably C:/, looking at that picture, while the lib is on D:/)

edit: Also, you shouldn't really be importing the library project directly from your SDK folders, Google recommend making a copy in your local project directory

Comment: Thanks a lot. Copying the project into the workspace when importing solved the problem.

Comment: @Coloneljesus Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try importing and copying the library project into your workspace, i think the problems is that the project doesn´t have the `appcompat_v7.jar` inside their `/bin` folder, thats why you have the red cross.

[image]

Comment: The downside of that is that you don't get all the resources in the appcompat library.

Comment: yes colonel, you´re right with the second option, , i have deleted the second one.