# Could not find abc.apk! - ERROR in console

Tags: android, console

I am trying to get a downloaded sample code to work - everything seems ok, however, everytime I run the project I get the error

```
[2011-11-03 10:21:43 - viewflow] Could not find viewflow.apk!
```

The app works fine but I just like to get rid of this error message in the console everytime the app starts.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

Go to Project->Properties

Select Android from left-hand side list

Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox

--

Or try to delete the project from the workspace and re-import it.

--

Original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk).