# I'm having some trouble adding OpenCV to a new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have made modifications to several example OpenCV projects within Android, however I am having some issues with using OpenCV successfully in a new Android project.

The [documentation on using OpenCV with Android](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html) says to complete the following steps to add OpenCV to an Android project -

- ensure the Android project is in the same workspace as OpenCV
- add a reference to the OpenCV project by going to **Properties > Android > Library > Add** and choosing the OpenCV Library project

I have followed both of these steps, however when I compile my application I receive the console error -

> Could not find OpenCV-2.3.1.apk!

Comment: I don't think you want the apk file. You probably want a tar/zip file that Eclipse can deal with once expanded. [This link for openCV explains more](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html)

Comment: That is the same link I provided in my original question. As I said in my question, I have followed all the steps provided in that documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When creating a new Android project, the only thing you need to do is

- add a reference to the OpenCV project by going to Properties > Android > Library > Add and choosing the OpenCV Library project

You should not then explicitly add OpenCV Library project into your new Android project's build path:

- add another reference to the OpenCV project by going to Properties > Java Build Path > Projects > add...

If you do latter step, you will get the exact error **Could not find OpenCV-2.3.1.apk!** described in the question.

Check out the New Android project's build path and remove OpenCV project if it exists, then give it another try and see if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem :) 

Oddly enough when I opened the project up again, the project was compiling and running perfectly in spite of the 'Could not find OpenCV-2.3.1.apk!' error. I removed the reference to OpenCV in the project's build path, and now no longer receive the error :) 

(I think possibly something may have been up with my OpenCV install which caused an unrelated error which was the real source of the problem, as it was automatically installed / updated again when I installed SimpleCV yesterday) 

Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, Glad to hear it helps:)

Comment: Could you please add a link to an Eclipse project already created? I would help us a lot

Answer (score 2):

When you add OpenCV from **Properties->Android->libarary->Add** you need to leave ***"Is Library"*** checkbox unchecked. Go to **Project->Properties->Android** and uncheck ***"Is Library"*** and then try again. It should solve your issue (it did for me) but if it doesn't please take a look at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk) as other people have found some other things to be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually unchecked at first - I tried checking it to see if that solved the issue but it didn't and gave me a different error though, so I unchecked it once again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I pulled in the jni_part.cpp file from a sample project. I forgot to change the names of the functions to fit the package name of the class I was using them from:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3Native_FindFeatures ->

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_<CLASSNAME_WITH_UNDERSCORES_INSTEAD_OF_DOTS>_<CLASS_NAME>_<METHOD_NAME>
```

Hope this helps someone.