# Could not find OpenCV Library - 2.4.3.apk! OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I’m having some trouble adding OpenCV to a new Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872089/im-having-some-trouble-adding-opencv-to-a-new-android-project)

I am writing an Android program, and am experiencing an error. After launch, the application cannot find the .apk file.

The console shows:

```
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] ------------------------------
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Android Launch!
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Performing org.opencv.prueba.algoritmos.InitialActivity activity launch
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Automatic Target Mode: using device '0019054d294eae'
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Uploading ProbandoAlgoritmos.apk onto device '0019054d294eae'
[2012-12-17 17:03:10 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Installing ProbandoAlgoritmos.apk...
[2012-12-17 17:03:12 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Success!
[2012-12-17 17:03:12 - OpenCV Library - 2.4.3] Could not find OpenCV Library - 2.4.3.apk!
[2012-12-17 17:03:12 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] Starting activity org.opencv.prueba.algoritmos.InitialActivity on device 0019054d294eae
[2012-12-17 17:03:12 - ProbandoAlgoritmos] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[ xxx ] cmp=xxxx }
```

Obviously, the application crashes.

There are not compiler errors, so the opencv library is imported, and Open CV Manager is installed on the device.

Why is this not finding the APK?

Answer (score 0):

if use Opencv4android2.4.3 you should install both "OpenCV_2.4.3_Manager_2.0_armeabi-v7a.apk" and "OpenCV_2.4.3_binary_pack_armv7a.apk" or you can visiit

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html

hope can help you!