# Could not find HelloAndroid.apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am struggeling with a problem compiling my first android hello world programm:

Here is my output of eclipse:

```
[2012-03-29 16:20:24 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2012-03-29 16:20:24 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-03-29 16:20:24 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-29 16:20:24 - HelloAndroid] Could not find HelloAndroid.apk!
```

Does anybody know a solution for the line could not finde HelloAndroid.apk?

greetings and thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean the project through the Project tab and build it again.

To verify that an .apk was actually created, you can check your name_of_project/bin/ folder and see if the name_of_project.apk is there.

It can be directly deleted from there as well to force re-building.

Comment: I did it but nothing happend, and there is no **apk** in *bin* folder

Answer (score 2):

Go to properties and uncheck the "is library". And there will be a magic,... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! This error suddenly occured and I have been searching the internet for half an hour! Thank you!

Comment: this is not fixing it

Comment: @Alireza This solution is one of many. Please try others answer as well. It works in most of the times. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me as well. Not only that previously build applications could not start due to mysterious "Could not find HelloAndroid.apk!", but also "Project --> Clean" would delete *.R and Build was NOT able to regenerate it. I tried literally everything posted about those two errors on this forum without success.

Then I remembered that I had (several hours before) update of Android tools. So, I did it again, and as it turned to be true, something went wrong due to previous update - I was offered new update and afterwards, EVERYTHING WENT BACK TO NORMAL. Project -> Clean was doing what is was supposed to do, *.R was generated, projects were free of errors, and missing APK was no more issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error.

And resolved by installing the build tools in Android-SDK Manager.
Check in your android-sdk manager that your

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted some of the solutions detailed in this question?
[Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

There are quite a few things that seem to cause this error; a few of those solutions have worked for me in the past. Let us know what steps you have already taken so we can further direct you where you need to go :-)