# Android Java Googlemap Could not find android-mapviewballoons.apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I have an Android google-map project in Eclipse that I am trying to use the balloons classes defined at https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons for. I have the project successfully building, and i believe linked, but when I go to run my project, I get the error message

```
[2012-09-03 14:07:30 - android-mapviewballoons] Could not find android-mapviewballoons.apk!
```

I am not entirely sure what this means as I am fairly to Android/Eclipse and linking files in Eclipse/Java. So I would appreciate any help I can get on how to solve this problem please.

Comment: Does this problem arise when you're trying to just run mapviewballoons project or does it arise when you run your project that uses mapviewballoons?

Comment: I am not running the mapviewballoons project. I am trying to use it in my own project.

Comment: I imported a reference into my project and trying to use it. As it said, it compiles with no problems but running it, I get the error message.

Comment: Anyone able to help me with this issue please?

Comment: @Kobojunkie if you clean and rebuild your project does the compiler complain? Have you updated eclipse lately, or changed any environmental variables? Try steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Comment: No the compiler does not complain at all. And I have tried at least 5 of the suggestions from that one link but still nothing changed.

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem is in how I add the library

Comment: @Kobojunkie these enviornmental issues are tricky to pin down. What version of Eclipse and what version of the Android SDK are you using? Any small changes you make to the environment can have roll on effects. It seems not an uncommon error: http://dotnetmackenzie.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/android-could-not-find-helloworldapk.html  However, would it be worth creating a new project and re-adding the library and seeing if it at least builds?

Comment: Android 2.3.3. I am using Eclipse 4.2. I will try to recreate again to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. If you are using more than one library, make sure MapBalloons is the top most one. Don't ask me why it doesn't work otherwise.

Right click project >> Properties >> Android >> Click up until library is at top.

**Make sure the library is added aswell** Click add >> choose the library. Clean project

[image]