# Could not find com_actionbarsherlock.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, actionbarsherlock

I've just installed *ActionBarSherlock*. I set up my *actionBar* as *getSupportActionBar*, as well as the proper themes - but I'm getting this error in the *Eclipse* console:

```
[2012-10-01 03:10:11 - com_actionbarsherlock] Could not find com_actionbarsherlock.apk!
```

The app runs fine, but I don't know if this is an indicator of future errors on other devices.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 18):

I was having this problem too. Even though everything was installing and working fine, Eclipse would always log this error about not finding an ActionBarSherlock.apk. There doesn't need to be an .apk because ActionBarSherlock is a library, not an app.

I fixed the problem by removing the ActionBarSherlock project from the required projects on the build path in my app's properties (Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Projects). The projects in this list are not for libraries, but rather other app projects that your project requires to be installed.

I originally placed the ActionBarSherlock project in this list of required projects in order to share the code with my project, to import the required classes, etc. The proper way to do this, however, was to add the ActionBarSherlock library to the library projects list (Project->Properties->Android->Library->Add...). Before I did this, I wasn't able to access the styles and other resources in the ActionBarSherlock project in my own. Now everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

See this discussion: [Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)