# create apk, after clean and (re)build

Tags: java, android, apk

I decided to clean and rebuild my app, because the apk didn't show the code changes.
Now after the building I haven't the apk in my bin folder and i can't run the app on my smartphone.

how can i create the apk?

Comment: It should automatically generate. Are there any errors in your application?

Comment: it won't generate the `apk` on building the project.

Comment: look your project again . I think you have some problem with your res folder or libs.

Comment: i have only warnings, eclipse doesn't show me errors.
maybe some problem with external library? (i'm using goolge play services because of new gmaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't the apk in my bin folder

It might be because of you have error in your code. When you run the project from Eclipse then it will automatically be created by apk builder.

In Eclipse, under Project Props, Build Path option, we can manually set the output folder.
Make sure you you not edited this.

Comment: @antedesk Read this thread, It might be issue in your case . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Answer (score 4):

When you run the project on the emulator, the `.apk` is generated on the bin directory. Keep in mind that just building the project (and not running it) will not output the `apk` file into the bin directory.

To export an unsigned `.apk` from Eclipse, **right-click** the project in the Package Explorer and select **Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package**. Then specify the file location for the unsigned `.apk`.

For signed apk:-

**Export -> Android -> Export Android Application -> YOUR_PROJECT_NAME -> Create new key store path -> Fill the detail -> Set the .apk location -> Now you can get your .apk file**

Now install the generated `apk` in your mobile.

**Note:-** I assume there are no errors in the project.

**Edit:-** Snapshots attached.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: ok i tryed to do what you say on my actually project and on another working project, without error, but the result is the same: eclipse could not find the project... i don't understand why... sorry for this silly questions

Comment: what did you try? to run it on the emulator? or export it?

Comment: to export (sorry), i can't run on the emulator

Comment: thank you for your time, the problem was that i'm using external library (google play services) and i checked isLibrary in my project properties. without the check i can generate the apk using the procedure described by you.