# Could not find xx.apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a very beginer, trying to create my first Android application. 
To do so, I use Eclipse and an AVD. I created my very first Class (called "Test") and when I run the project it says "Could not find Test.apk!"

I had a look at many solutions an internet:
- delete and import
- clean up my project (I have only one class so there is not much to clean

And it still does not work.

Do you have any idea about how to proceed to fix this up?

Many thank for you help.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information to know what's wrong. What steps did you take to create this application?

Does your class Test extend the class Activity?

If it does, is it declared in your project's AndroidManifest.xml file?

Also, make sure that your project is not set up as a library project. Right click on your project's name, select Properties->Android and make sure that IsLibrary is not checked.

Comment: Can you post your Test.java and AndroidManifest.xml files?

Comment: Islibrary is not checked.
Ok I have been unclear, my project is called Test, my activity called MainActivity and therefore the class qhich interest me is called MainActivity as well.
My class MainActivity is in the xml file.

Comment: Ok here is my MainActivity class:
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private TextView coucou = null;
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   coucou = new TextView(this);
   coucou.setText("Bonjour, vous me devez 1 000 000€.");
   setContentView(coucou);
 }
 
}

Comment: "I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers which I downloaded just yesterday in Eclipse official website so I guess the version is not the problem." Did you also install ADT? Your activity is fine BTW, mais je ne vais pas te donner un millions d'euros ;)

Comment: On peut toujours essayer :p
Yes I installed the ADT add-on, actually my emulator is started and is apparently normal.

Comment: Ok guys I just found out what was wrong.
It seems that when I install my SDK,I asked him to install the Tools, but it did not (don't know why) install the Android SDK Buid-tools....So problem solved, many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:-

- Sometimes the apk file is not generated simply because there are some
  android build error in your project, In this case, *right click your
  project, choose Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties*.
- Is your project termed as library, in this case, Go to
  Project->Properties--> Select Android from left-hand side list -->
  Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox
- Delete R.java file then clean build project or restart eclipse, this
  will force the workspace to be rebuild.
- what version of eclipse are you using,  version of Eclipse
  using(Ganymede – 3.4) is not compatible with the latest version of
  the SDK. Try updating Eclipse..

Hope this helps..

Comment: Ok so first thank you both for your quick answers. 
- Islibrary is unckecked
- I did the Fix Project Properties and Clean things, but it does not work
But I do not know what and where the R.java file is.

More information about what I did. I created an new Android Applcation Project (called Test) and a blank activity called MainActivity.
Eclipse geenrated automatically my project with a java class called "MainActivity". I modified this class in order to display a simple message.
But when I run the project, it does not work....

Comment: ok, try with other possible fix mentioned above, let me know if you are still having problem..

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers which I downloaded just yesterday in Eclipse official website so I guess the version is not the problem.

Comment: Well, in that case, 2nd and 4th case is not solution try 1st and 3rd'

Comment: R.java is autoGenerated file, it is in gen folder created by Eclipse itself.

Comment: yes but it seems that this file has not been generated. How can I do this?

Comment: Ahh, there you are, there must be problem with your .xml files in layout section. check for problems there.. goto Wndow-->Show view --> Problems.. clean build your project and you will get to know your prob there..

Comment: I just tried to clean build but nothing appears in the Problem window (and why would there be any problem in xml layout file?I did not modify it)

Comment: Ok guys I just found out what was wrong.
It seems that when I install my SDK,I asked him to install the Tools, but it did not (don't know why) install the Android SDK Buid-tools....So problem solved, many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @user2511974 If your problem is solved then you should post your experience in answer section and mark that as solved. It will benefit other who might have same problem