# PhoneGap Android "Could not find *.apk"

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

i tried to make my first phonegap app and now i try to run this as an android application on eclipse, but the console tells me always:

```
[2013-06-24 13:21:08 - PhoneGapAndroid1] Android Launch!
[2013-06-24 13:21:08 - PhoneGapAndroid1] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-24 13:21:08 - PhoneGapAndroid1] Could not find PhoneGapAndroid1.apk!**
```

Comment: possible duplication of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Comment: no sorry, it doesn't work :/

Comment: uhm, try to uninstall and reinstall the android libs with SDK manager.exe, do a Clean on your eclipse project, and verify if you're trying to run the correct project