# Imported project throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

So I imported an existing project to eclipse and I have a lot of trouble making it work. The project came with three other library projects:

- google_play_services-lib
- CaptureActivity
- PortraitQR

As soon as I imported the project, I went under 'Java Build Path' and added paths for needed jars:
[image]

After I successfully added the needed jars, I went on to the libraries. I imported all three needed libraries (that I was given along with the project) and it all went well:
[image]

After that I also made sure private libraries are checked under the export tab:
[image]

After I was done importing the project I tried to run it but it crashed instantly. This is the logcat file:

```
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{si.dvanadva.evanturist/si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-17 17:33:36.543: E/AndroidRuntime(25965):    ... 11 more
```

I can see from the logcat file that the problem is 'finding MainActivity class'

Solutions that I have tried so far:

- Checked if MainActivity is correctly declared in the AndroidManifest file (it is)
- Checked private libraries under the export tab
- Deleted bin folder and cleaned project
- I also tried declaring activities in the AndroidManifest file by not including the package name, like this: android:name=".activityname"
- Deleted the previous version of the app from my phone and tried compiling again
- Checked for si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk in workspace project but I can't find it (am I missing it?)
- Did [this](http://dotnetmackenzie.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/android-could-not-find-helloworldapk.html) to set JAVA_HOME but it doesn't work
- Started a new android application project and copied files in there

Maybe I also tried something else but I forgot to mention it, I've been working on this for quite a while now and I'm running out of things to try. I'll greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: "/data/app/si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk" -- This is the path?

Comment: Path for MainActivity.class is different. It's workspace/Evanturist/bin/classes/si/dvanadva/evanturist, is this causing the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the path be a directory? si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk? Did you check?

Comment: I checked, I can't find si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk anywhere, there's not even data/app directory

Comment: Try putting your file in the `src` directory in your project folder.

Comment: @SteveP. There is, src/si/dvanadva/evanturist/'java files'. I also took the MainActivity.class that I found in bin folder and added it to src/si/dvanadva/evanturist/ (if that's what you meant) but nothing changes.

Comment: @Matthew hmm.... no idea, then.

Comment: How about you do a search in project for si.dvanadva.evanturist-1.apk? Seems like something referencing to it.

Comment: @SajalDutta I did, opened project in workspace and searched for the file but it didn't find anything

Comment: One last thing- 1. Go to Project-->Properties. 2. Select Android from lefthand side panel. 3. Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox.

Comment: @SajalDutta It was never checked in the first place :/

Comment: Man!! I hate it when this thing happens with Android and Eclipse. The first thing I do when something like this happens is - clean and rebuild. close the project within eclipse. then exit eclipse. launch eclipse. reopen the project. Usually these steps fix these issues. I really have no other idea.

Comment: @SajalDutta I know, these things are just too frustrating. I tried everything you just said...multiple times. I stopped counting how many times I re-imported the project, re-cleaned it, deleted bin folder etc. etc. I just don't know what to do anymore. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: This one has a lot of possible solutions. You might wanna see and check other related Q&A. Sorry buddy, wish I could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fairly certain I've seen things like this happen when I haven't imported the code into Eclipse, but have tried to run the library from its downloaded location e.g. for Google Play Game Services:

> Import the TypeANumber and BaseGameUtils code from the Android samples
>   into your workspace. To do this in Eclipse: Click File > Import >
>   Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace. Browse to the
>   directory where you downloaded TypeANumber on your development machine
>   and click OK to import the files. Perform the same steps for
>   BaseGameUtils.

(I got this from https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)

Also ,although this is not an exact fit for your problem:

[Google Player Game Service Error: Can't build the sample game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731591/google-player-game-service-error-cant-build-the-sample-game)

Comment: Yes!!!! I can't believe I didn't try this yet! The problem was that added a library project google play services from some other directory, not from downloaded location. Thank you so much!! You deserve the bounty award without a doubt :)

Comment: You are welcome. I spent quite a lot of time reading the other contributions and going through my notes before I stumbled on the likely cause.

Comment: @Matthew I think you should award the bounty if he helped solve it (I'm not sure how the expiration works; the system is complicated IMO). I was about to ask you the project to take a look, but looks like it's already solved :)

Comment: @ADTC yes! thank you for reminding me, I wanted to reward the bounty days ago but it wouldn't let me because I had to wait another 20 hours and then I completely forgot about it, sorry about that :)