# Google Player Game Service Error: Can't build the sample game

Tags: android, google-play-games, build-error

I can't build the sample game `TypeANumberChallenge` provided by Google (see [GitHub](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber)). Got the following error message:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient. Fix the build path then try building this project

The type com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    MainActivity.java   /TypeANumber/src/com/kerrywei/games/tanc
```

I did include the project library `BaseGameUtils` and google-play-services-lib as described by [readme](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) and [Google Play Services Guides](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), but still got the error, and can't just compile...

Update:
I tried to remove `TypeANumberChallenge` and redo the whole process and got a new error when trying to add `BaseGameUtils` as library:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".
Path must include project and resource name: /BaseGameUtils
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by reading [Google Play Services Guides](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

> 4. Make a copy of the Google Play services library project. Copy the library project at
>      `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`
>      to the location where you maintain your Android app projects. If you
>      are using Eclipse, import the library project into your workspace.
>      Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into
>      Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

You CANNOT use the lib project in SDK folder DIRECTLY...
What a joke..

Comment: If you are updating the google-play-services_lib you will be required to re-import the project.  The new version updates are not automatically added to the Eclipse workspace, only the SDK folder, and so will not be visible to your other Eclipse projects.