# Couldn't find *.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I try to get on Android Programming.
When I try to launch my application on Eclipse (a simple Hello World), I get :

```
[2014-02-10 21:32:40 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-02-10 21:32:40 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-10 21:32:40 - HelloWorld] Could not find HelloWorld.apk
```

I try a lot of thing I found (Restart Eclipse, Check-Uncheck the "is Library"..) none of them worked.
Moreover, the LogCat seems to be empty.

Does someone have a solution for me ?

Thanks.

(Please forgive my english, I am not native).

Comment: delete the R.Java file in /Gen folder.

Comment: look for some error message in Console.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk

Answer (score 1):

- Refresh your proyect <kbd>F5</kbd>, then delete your `/gen` and `/bin` folders, `Project > Build All`
- `Project > Clean and then Project >Build All`.
- Probably you have your project defined as a library!

  Go to `Project > Properties > Android`

**Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox**.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you have not given the permission for the installation of third party applications on your device.