# Could not find BaseGameUtils.apk, Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm following this tutorial to add google play services into my LibGDX game:
http://fortheloss.org/tutorial-set-up-google-services-with-libgdx/ -  After doing all the steps, I tried to test the game, but it doesn't work.

In the **console** I get this error:

```
[2016-03-16 11:55:05 - escal8-android] ------------------------------
[2016-03-16 11:55:05 - escal8-android] Android Launch!
[2016-03-16 11:55:05 - escal8-android] adb is running normally.
[2016-03-16 11:55:05 - escal8-android] Performing com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android.AndroidLauncher activity launch
[2016-03-16 11:55:05 - escal8-android] Uploading escal8-android.apk onto device '4100ad01e444a105'
[2016-03-16 11:55:08 - escal8-android] Installing escal8-android.apk...
[2016-03-16 11:55:21 - escal8-android] Success!
[2016-03-16 11:55:21 - BaseGameUtils] Could not find BaseGameUtils.apk!
[2016-03-16 11:55:21 - escal8-android] Starting activity com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android.AndroidLauncher on device 4100ad01e444a105
[2016-03-16 11:55:23 - escal8-android] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android/.AndroidLauncher }
```

And in **LogCat**, I get this:

```
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328): Process: com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android, PID: 5328
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:267)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:309)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:86)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.konigvanzwol.escal8.android-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     ... 18 more
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-16 11:00:25.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5328):         ... 19 more
```

I've tried pretty much all of the suggested solutions I could find, including everything suggested here: [Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)
, (except reinstalling eclipse). But no luck so far :(

I also found this link: [Could not find BaseGameUtils.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599635/could-not-find-basegameutils-apk) , which seemed helpful, but I didn't quite understand the steps I should go through in the developer console to make this right. Perhaps someone could clarify?

Comment: For the next time: Please paste the errors of the logcat as text, not as "unsearchable" images. It will help others with a similar exception to find a solution

Comment: ah, stupid, I'll edit my post!

Comment: This might not be you issue but base game activity is dead and `gamehelper` should not be used anymore. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oSoaFLuTwM There are only old and obsolete tutorials out there and only official sources can be trusted to supply proper information. However I made the number game example into a LibGDX project here: https://github.com/madmenyo/NumberGame it's a fully working example of the official `NumberGame`.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I guess I'll try some other tutorials then. I also tried to import your example into eclipse, but it gives me this error: "Error in runnable 'Creating Gradle model'
Cannot convert URL 'F:/android/leys' to a file.
See error log for details."...