# Robotium: Could not find XXX.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, robotium, android-testing, ui-testing

I am very new to Robotium tool. I am facing issue for the execution of first test in Robotium. Please help

**Step1**:
I created Android virtual device in using eclipse and ADT.
Details: Android 5.1.1 - API level 22
CPU - ARM
Virtual device created and launched successfully.

**Step2**:
Then Installed application apk using command line 
details: adb install path-of-apk\XXX.apk

**Step3**
Created Android Test project. Imported Robotium SOLO jar as external library.
Android.jar is under Android 5.1.1
Robotium jar is under Referenced libraries

**Step4**
Changed Target package to correct one captured from Hierarchical view

**Step5**
Created test class and tried to execute it using Android JUNIT

**Error i am getting is**
    [2015-12-12 01:22:50 - Robotium_Calc] Android Launch!
    [2015-12-12 01:22:50 - Robotium_Calc] adb is running normally.
    [2015-12-12 01:22:50 - Robotium_Calc] Could not find XXX.apk!

Update: I am using Windows OS and Java 1.7

Sorry. May be this question has been asked several times here but i could not find solution which solve my problem.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, may it sound stupid, but are you sure that on device (which you want to use to test) while you try to run is your app with not changed before package name

Comment: Sorry. i did not get your question. can you please reframe?

Comment: Well, I thought that you haven't installed properly an app on your device

Comment: No it is installed well. i can open it manually too. By the way i am using emulator

Comment: so it must a problem with eclipse configuration. Try solutions in the first link in post I've added below. It's StackOverflow discussion.

Comment: Yes i tried all those configurations. but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I've edited my post and add some new links with solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

However i think i was facing the issue because there was incompatibility between eclipse, JDK and Android version i was using.
Initial config : Eclipse Indigo, JDK1.7 and Android 5.1.1 - API level 22

I changed configuration to: Eclipse Luna, JDK 1.7 and Android 5.1.1 - API level 22

So updating Eclipse to Luna solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a problem with your Android configuration in Eclipse IDE. Try to solve by using solutions from:
[Android Eclipse - Could not find *.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)

I'm not already using Robotium, but please check also a configuration for your Robotium library. Read (if you haven't done yet) this great tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robotium/article.html

EDIT: if you still not have a problem fixed read these:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/ok44ta96GZc/YrNH3BKKVjgJ

http://mobilemancer.com/2010/12/01/could-not-find-yourapp-apk/

http://azeemhassan.com/find-helloworld-apk/

Well, according to [this](http://errorh.com/android-error-could-not-find-apk/) site I can say that is a quite often problem with Eclipse bad configuration

Answer (score 0):

Probably your .APK has not been generated inside `/gen/bin/` folder, check first if your project doesn´t have any errors.

I you  don´t have any errors  just make a `Refresh` -> `Build`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But there is no error in my project. Also i tried refresh and build again, Executed again, same issue.

Comment: What to you mean by libraries.?

Comment: Your project is working with library projects. go to Properties - > Android -> Library section http://i.stack.imgur.com/e9uWl.jpg

Comment: No. Library section is empty.